# Calculate percentages values of groups versus total of values in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Consider the following table:
[image]

I want to calculate the percentage of each grouped sku/identifier combination in order to get this result:
[image]

How can this be done in polars in a single action? I am aware of grouping, but I don't know how I can instruct it to then calculate the percentage amount vs the total of the summed group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sum_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sum_horizontal.html) to calculate total first, put it into variable to avoid cluttering the dataframe, and then calculate fractions. This way you can easily reuse the code later for differently named columns / any number of columns:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [f'identifier {x}' for x in [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]],
    "sku1": [4, 2, 3, None, 1],
    "sku2": [None, 3, None, 3, None],
})

kcols = ['id']
vcols = pl.all().exclude(kcols)

total = df.select(vcols.sum()).sum_horizontal()

print(df.group_by(kcols).agg(vcols.sum() / total))



shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ id           ┆ sku1  ┆ sku2   │
│ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str          ┆ f64   ┆ f64    │
╞══════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ identifier 1 ┆ 0.375 ┆ 0.1875 │
│ identifier 2 ┆ 0.25  ┆ 0.1875 │
└──────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Actually this was the better answer. Sku's can and will vary

Answer (score 2):

First, we create a dataframe with the data from the example.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "sku1": [4, 2, 3, None, 1],
    "sku2": [None, 3, None, 3, None],
})
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ sku1 ┆ sku2 │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4    ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
│ 2   ┆ 3    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ 3    │
│ 2   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

We can first compute the overall total across ids and sku columns and, then, use this total in a `group_by` / `agg` context as follows.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        total=pl.col("sku1").sum() + pl.col("sku2").sum()
    )
    .group_by("id")
    .agg(
        pl.col("sku1").sum() / pl.col("total").first(),
        pl.col("sku2").sum() / pl.col("total").first(),
    )
)
```

**Output.**

*Note.* Without setting `maintain_order=True` in the `group_by` call, the final order of the ids may vary.

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬────────┐
│ id  ┆ sku1  ┆ sku2   │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ f64   ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0.375 ┆ 0.1875 │
│ 2   ┆ 0.25  ┆ 0.1875 │
└─────┴───────┴────────┘
```

If you prefer percentage values in [0, 100] as in the example data, you can simply add a multiplication with 100 in the aggregation.